# How to Display the Second Tag in WordPress Post

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using currently the below codes to display all tags with posts,

```
<h3 class="entry-title">                
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>"><?php $posttags = get_the_tags(); if ($posttags) {
    echo '<ul class="myitems">';
    foreach ($posttags as $tag)
    {
        echo '<li>' . $tag->name . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>'; } ?>          </a>            </h3>
```

**Note:** I always assign only two tags to each wordpress post, Now i want that the code should display the the second tag only. for example, if i assigned two tags, ( **animal**, **dog** ) the code should display only **dog** tag.

**Summary:** The above code display all the tags while i need to do someone changes in the above code to display only the second tag used not the first tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't shared it's implementation, I'm assuming your `get_the_tags` function always returns an array with the tag you want in the second index. Try the following:

```
<h3 class="entry-title">                
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>">
        <?php 
            $posttags = get_the_tags();
            if ($posttags) {
                echo '<ul class="myitems">';
                echo '<li>' . $posttags[1]->name . '</li>';
                echo '</ul>'; 
            } 
        ?>          
    </a>            
</h3>
```

Comment: the code is not working, you can see both tags are still displaying here: https://readnational.com/national-symbols/norway/

Comment: @John This suggests that you haven't updated the code yet since two `<li>` tags are present, and my answer contains only one.

Comment: Thanks bundles, i forgot to add the code in child theme, i past earlier somewhere else, Thanks bundles it worked fine

Comment: i accepted your answer bundles of thanks